# How to make a dynamic, selectable list under a text field in a webpage (like Googles instant search)

Tags: php, textfield, html, dynamic-list

I'm looking for a way to create a dynamic list below a text field on a web page.
This list needs to be selectable (by mouse click and arrow-down-key).
The selected item shall be in the text-field after selecting it.

It should look and behave like the google instant search.

I did finish the instant serach with this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

The only thing missing now is to make the list selectable and put the selected item in the text field. (after that the list shall disappear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_array.html

And there are many many more to choose from. good luck :-)